# SCIP solver JNI: how to set the memory?

Tags: scip

So I'm using [SCIP-JNI](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt) in my scala project. 
SCIP's JNI-based libearies make calls to binary C-based solver to do the optimizatin. Is there a way to set the memory for the solver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have added functions to [JSCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt) such that one can set explicitly some parameters in the same way as in SCIP. For example,

```
scip.setRealParam("limits/memory", 1000.0)
```

sets a memory limit of 1GB.